# Как правильно перенести код в отдельный метод и вызвать метод?

Tags: java

Программа открывает.csv файл и выводит его содержимое.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path filePath = Paths.get("xxx.csv");
        try {
            String content = Files.readString(filePath);
            System.out.println(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл. Возможно, файл не находится в нужной директории.");      
        }
    }
}
```

Как правильно перенести этот участок кода в отдельный метод типа такого:

```
private String readFileContentsOrNull(String path) 
{
    try {
        return Files.readString(Path.of(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл. Возможно, файл не находится в нужной директории.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

И как его вызвать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String readFileContents(String namefile)
    Path filePath = Paths.get(filename);
    try {
        return Files.readString(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Невозможно прочитать файл. Возможно, файл не находится в нужной директории.";      
    }
```

Вызов такой

```
System.out.println(readFileContents("xxx.csv"));
```